# How to convert a lot of passwords from txt files into keepass database?

Tags: keepass

I've got almost a hundred txt's without solid structure which contains two or three lines with login/password/email in varying order and the website title in the each file's name. How can I structurize the files and put them into keepass with less efforts than doing it individually for every file by hand?

Comment: If the order is varying then computer won't be able to distinguish login from password.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you'd have to find something in each file that differentiates login, password, & email. Then re-arrange so they're all in the same place in each file to automatically grab the wanted info. I'd try `grep` and `cut`, or `awk`/`sed`.

But if there's nothing to tell which is which, then maybe a script/program to read each file, display a line and let you manually pick what it is, then save the results to a new file. A little faster than manually cut & paste, but not much.

There are `grep` patterns to find email addresses, but if any password has an "@" and "." it could mistake it for an email.

Manually copy & pasting may be the easiest way to go, it's "only" 100 files, not 10,000.

But, if you just want to securely encrypt the passwords, and don't need to use keepass, you could zip then encrypt all the files with `gpg` / `pgp` , or an encrypted container like LUKS or truecrypt (still pretty secure, if unsupported now)